# Using template literals in ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, template-literals

I have a ruby on rails application that has a form that injects new form fields using javascript.  The injected form fields are in a template literal.  The template is here:

```
    $("#formSet").append(`
            <div class="row itemGroup">
        <div class="form-group col">
        <div class="input-group">
        <input type="number" min="0" value="1" name="quotation[items_attributes][${count}][qty]" id="item-qty-${count}" class="form-control qty">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-5">
        <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="quotation[items_attributes][${count}][description]" id="item-description-${count}" class="form-control desc">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col">
        <div class="input-group">
        <input type="number" value="0" name="quotation[items_attributes][${count}][price]" step="any" min="0" id="item-price-${count}" class="form-control price">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col">
        <div class="input-group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="quotation[items_attributes][${count}][tax]" value="1" id="item-tax-${count}" class="form-control tax"  checked="checked">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col">
        <div class="input-group">
        <input type="number" value="0.00" class="form-control subtotal" name="[items_attributes][${count}][subtotal]" readonly>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
`);
```

However when I try to precompile my assets for production, I get:

```
ExecJS::RuntimeError: SyntaxError: Unexpected character '`'
```

Is there a way to use ES6 template literals with the rails precompiler, or is there a way I can append the items without using a template literal?

Comment: Did you close your append function, or was it just an error when you pasted your code?

Comment: Remove extra `(` following `.append(`

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo on my part, the error remains the same though, unexpected character `

Comment: It could be the version of Node.js you're using or the JavaScript library for ExecJS isn't ES6 compatible yet. Update it?

Comment: Ah the obligatory down vote with no explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present Rails default configuration is not enough for using `ES6`. There are many ways that you can setup your project for using `ES6` even unfortunately there isn't really a 'standard' way of doing this.

**Option 1:**
If your rails version is 4.2 and Sprockets 3, then you can use https://github.com/rmacklin/sprockets-bumble_d to add ES6 support.

**Option 2:**
Upgrade Sprockets to version 4, then use either https://github.com/fnando/babel-schmooze-sprockets or https://github.com/babel/ruby-babel-transpiler to add babel for ES6 support.

**Option 3:**
If you are using Rails 5.1 then use webpack (either instead of or alongside sprockets).  Rails 5.1 introduce native webpack (and thus babel) support via the [webpacker gem](https://github.com/rails/webpacker). This may be the more difficult option for an existing application. There is a good article about it here: https://medium.com/statuscode/introducing-webpacker-7136d66cddfb#.cb4sixyah hope it will help you.